# Why does Word switch to italics each time I start a new line?

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts

I am busy with a numbered list, of the straight 1,2,3 type. All was going well until about twenty minutes ago, when every time I type a line, it types fine in regular text, but when I press enter and go to the next line/number, Word switches to italics. The numbers aren't formatted in italics though.

What on Earth could cause this to happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: The technical term for this is "whacked out".  It isn't normal behavior, and there is no information here to go on.  People can only guess at the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal. Word try to guess what your next style will be by checking your previous entries. Try this to eliminate this behavior:

Word 2007-2013

> click on the Home tab / Styles group / Styles dialog launcher (the little arrow in the right bottom corner) to launch the Styles Pane. Then > click on the style you using and click
>   on modify. Check the name of the style in the "Style for following
>   Paragraph" input field. If it is something unexpected, change it and
>   save it to normal template.

Word 2016

> click on the Home tab / Styles group / Styles dialog launcher (the little arrow in the right bottom corner) to launch the Styles Pane. Then > click on the style you using and click
>   on modify. Go to format and select Fonts. In the input Field select +Body and check if there is something unusual.